# How can I show values from a JSON source on the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: html, css, json, taskbar

I would like to create some kind of toolbar or something on my Windows Taskbar that would sit near by clock and display one or two number values from a JSON source. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplishing this?

If this is doable with some kind of HTML/CSS formatting that would be great so that I could control things a bit more, but I'm open to whatever is available.

Comment: Perhaps <script>
window.status = "Some text in the status bar!!";
</script>

Comment: @JamesKing I'm actually looking for something outside of the browser, I don't want the title of the browser to show the information, I want it on my Windows Taskbar like the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without a C/C - related language. Maybe this can be a good starting point: `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290013/Formless-System-Tray-Application`

Comment: I like this, but it seems like i could only really display one number at a time, I should have been more specific in my question and stated that I'd like to display multiple numbers, and i don't quite think having multiple instances of this tray icon is what i'm looking for. Thank you for the link though, I'll definitely learn some stuff from it.